# Load Error in unity C# program

Tags: c#, unity-container

This is my Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration;

namespace UnityDemo2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IUnityContainer container;
            container = new UnityContainer();
        }
    }
}
```

I get this run-time error when it reaches the last line.

```
Could not load type 'System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

My target framework is .Net Framework 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no [System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.introspectionextensions.aspx) class in .Net framework 4.0. You must use .Net 4.5 for it.

Comment: Excuse me. But are you sure of this?

Comment: Do you see provided link?

Answer (score 1):

Check your references/version of Unity. Afaik its a .Net 4.5 class so its definitely something wrong with your project config.